# Сравнение двух массивов(изображений) OpenCv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Итак,сравниваю два изображений image & imagesrav (полная копия первого изображения), пытаюсь сделать так, что если изображения 1 и 2 равны, то выводится, что они равны. Пытаюсь использовать функцию absdiff, но не понимаю, как с ней работать.

UPD:
Понял, что нужно работать с bitwise_xor, но не понял, что добавить в код.

```
Mat image = imread("D:\\Arry\\chesir.jpg", 1);
Mat imagesrav = imread("D:\\Arry\\chesir.jpg", 1);

if (image.empty())
    std::cout << "Image not";

Mat result;



(absdiff(image, imagesrav, result));

if (static_cast<bool>(result) = 0)
    print("Yes");
else
    print("No");
```

Comment: Попробуйте `cv.countNonZero(result) == 0`

Comment: Да вроде в прошлой ветке про countNonZero было сказано